# Cannot run vb6/make command in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

My script contains the following code.

```
Set objShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ObjShell.Run "vb6/make Project1.vbp Project1.exe"
```

But my script doesn't make my project compile into exe.

I have the visual basic project Project1.vbp in the same folder which contains the script and the path for vb6 is also set in the Environment variable.

However when I tried to compile the project manually into exe it worked fine, by the command given below

```
vb6/make Project1.vbp Project1.exe
```

Kindly suggest some way to resolve my script's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use full paths in sutch cases, I presume the error is there.
You can catch the error produced in the following way.
Here with a Ruby script I want to run but deliberatly made a mistake in the path.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
command = "cmd.exe /S /C ruby ""C:\Users\Gebruiker\ruby\excel\ru.rb"""
Set objWshScriptExec = objShell.Exec(command)
Set objStdOut = objWshScriptExec.StdOut
Set objStdErr = objWshScriptExec.StdErr

While Not objStdOut.AtEndOfStream
  WScript.echo objStdOut.ReadLine
Wend

While Not objStdErr.AtEndOfStream
  WScript.echo objStdErr.ReadLine
Wend

' ruby: No such file or directory -- C:/Users/Gebruiker/ruby/excel/ru.rb (LoadError)
```

Comment: Finally my script worked and the credit goes to you.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes

```
Set objWshScriptExec=objShell.Exec("cmd.exe /S /C vb6/make ""Project1.vbp""")
```

And it worked.
Since I am a beginner in vbscript, I don't know the function of

```
/S /C
```

so please let me know.

Comment: hi Ankit, see here http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true